# How do i solve overloaded function with no contextual type information error?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, linked-list, arguments

I'm doing a program about doubly linked list. I have function `find` that helps locate, if per se, no. 7 is anywhere within that list. This function works fine and returns pointer to that node.

Then I have function `afterElement` that inserts for example no. 3 after no. 7, So it uses pointer to `find` function as parameter. I think this is where the problem stems from, but I might be wrong, you be the judge.

I wanna know, how can I correctly use this function? Is there something wrong with how I pass parameters or else? 
The error I get is "overloaded function with no contextual type information".

Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
int data;
node* prev;
node* next;
};

node* find(int,node*&);
void afterElement(int,int,node*&,node*&,node* (*find)(int, node*&));

int main() {
    node* head = NULL;
    node* tail = NULL;
    // The program itself has a menu that allows for input of value in list but
    // for the sake of relevancy and shortness of code I dropped it out from here

    int x, y;
    cout << "Insert 2 values: value you wish to insert, and value you wish to insert it after. ";
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    afterElement(x,y,head,tail,(*find)(y,head)); // here is the error "overloaded function..."
    return 0;
}

node* find(int x,node*& head) {
    node* curr = head;
    while ((curr != NULL) && (curr->data != x))
        curr = curr->next;
    return curr;
}

void afterElement(int x,int after,node*& head,node*& tail,node* (*find)(int x, node*& head)) {
node* N;
node* compared = (*find)(after,head);
N->data = x;
if (compared == NULL)
    cout << "There is no element " << after << " in the list!\n";
else {
    if (compared->next == NULL) {
        compared->next = N;
        N->prev = compared;
        N->next = NULL;
        tail = N;
    } else {
        compared->next->prev = N;
        N->next = compared->next;
        compared->next = N;
        N->prev = compared;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you pass the function pointer to `afterElement()` function instead of calling `find()` function from it? And references to pointers as function parameters... why?

Comment: `afterElement` has a function pointer as its last argument, but you passed a pointer to node, ie the result of a call to `find`: `(*find)(y,head)` calls the function, if you want to pass the function just use `&find` as the value argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a function as an argument to another function, you just need to use the function name, not the entire call expression.

```
afterElement(x,y,head,tail,find);
```

This is the minimal fix that causes your program to compile. [Live demo](https://ideone.com/uhCWPx). Note this only demonstrates that the compilation errors are fixed, not that the program works!

In addition, because you are `using namespace std`, you are getting incomprehensible error messages, since the compiler cannot figure out what `find` you have in mind, your own or `std::find`. If you get rid of `using namespace std`, your error message becomes much clearer:

```
error: cannot convert ‘node*’ to ‘node* (*)(int, node*&)’
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/gHzrdi). Never use `using namespace std`.

However you may want to consider removing `find` from the parameter list of `afterElement`. `afterElement` doesn't need to be told which function to call in order to find an element.

```
void afterElement(int x,int after,node*& head,node*& tail)
```

would work just fine.

Passing a pointer to a node instead of `int after` will also work:

```
void afterElement(int x, node* after, node*& head, node*& tail)
```

Call `afterElement(x, y, find(x, head), head, tail)` to use this variant. Note you don't need to say `(*find)(x, head)`.

There are more problems with your code than this compilation error. For example

```
node* N;
...
N->data = x;
```

is incorrect. You have not initialised `N`, it doesn't point anywhere, so you cannot use `->` on it.

Another problem is that your program never modifies `head`, so the list doesn't have a chance to contain anything. This perhaps should be fixed by adding more functions (maybe something like `beforeElement`).

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! Also thank you for pointing out the uninitialized node! :D

Answer (score 0):

I observe that you want to pass the "find" function as an argument to afterElement function.

Sure you can pass a function as an argument to other function. A function also gets stored in a memory location. This memory location is stored in the variable named same as the function name (in this case "find").

Now you are receiving the find function argument as a pointer in the afterElement function, so it is expecting an address, but you are passing the whole function. That's the reason why it is giving a compilation error.
The correct code looks like :

```
#include <iostream>using namespace std;

struct node {
int data;
node* prev;
node* next;
};

node* find(int,node*&);
void afterElement(int,int,node*&,node*&,node* (*find)(int, node*&));

int main() {
    node* head = NULL;
    node* tail = NULL;
    // The program itself has a menu that allows for input of value in list but
    // for the sake of relevancy and shortness of code I dropped it out from here

    int x, y;
    cout << "Insert 2 values: value you wish to insert, and value you wish to insert it after. ";
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    afterElement(x,y,head,tail,find); // modified the passing argument
    return 0;
}

node* find(int x,node*& head) {
    node* curr = head;
    while ((curr != NULL) && (curr->data != x))
        curr = curr->next;
    return curr;
}

void afterElement(int x,int after,node*& head,node*& tail,node* (*find)(int x, node*& head)) {
node* N;
node* compared = (*find)(after,head);
N->data = x;
if (compared == NULL)
    cout << "There is no element " << after << " in the list!\n";
else {
    if (compared->next == NULL) {
        compared->next = N;
        N->prev = compared;
        N->next = NULL;
        tail = N;
    } else {
        compared->next->prev = N;
        N->next = compared->next;
        compared->next = N;
        N->prev = compared;
    }
}
}
```

I have checked with compilation, but check once for the results you are expecting.
Thanks.